# Difference between MongoDB PECL driver and Composer PHPLIB?

Tags: php, mongodb, composer-php

In most PHP tutorials I see example of connection to MongoDB using Composer library like:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; // Composer
$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
```

But in another tutorials I see:

```
<?php
$conn = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
```

*(Without using a Composer library!! Looks like Composer is not necessary in this case.)*

1. What is the difference and good practice to use?
2. Which method have better performance?

Comment: The first one is using a [PHP-library](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library) (a wrapper that helps and simplifies things) and the second one is using the MongoDB-extension directly. I would go with the first.

Comment: You mean PECL is a wrapper and composer using extension directly? In my opinion it should be the opposite.

Comment: No. What you install with PECL is the PHP _extension_ (compiled code written in some other language, usually C, that exposes an API to PHP). Installing the extension is mandatory if you want to use Mongo with PHP. The composer package `mongodb/mongodb` is a PHP _library_ (a wrapper for the PHP extensions API, making it easier to use). This is optional but recommended.

Comment: *"But in another tutorials I see"* - Please share the links to these tutorials within your question. I personally want to contact anyone publishing things like this to set them straight. The need to install from **two** different sources is indeed confusing and somewhat of a failing but nobody should be publishing tutorials that say differently. Being a little more succinct than "simplifies", what the PHPLIB package actually does is present an API which is consistent with all other language implementations. The "core" driver does not have this and is mostly "raw" interfaces